Can I set up the Token extensions (Token 2022) on a Solana spl-token I already made?
I have a guide to mint an SPL-Token and I wanted to know what do I change to use the new Token-2022 or the Token extensions? In the guide it says the command is:
spl-token create-token
What should I change about that? And is all the rest of the process the same?

If you want to use token-2022 to create your token, you'll need to do a few things during your call to create-token:

specify --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
add any flags for extensions you want to add, ie --enable-metadata: you can see all of the possibilities at https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions

Note that you cannot add extensions to an existing mint.

Thank you. Can I put a tag for the extension and then as long as the extension is tagged, modify it later?

There's no concept of "tagging", you must initialize all extensions before initializing the mint. But you can certainly modify the parameters of individual extensions

Thanx a lot, could you give me your opinion on the best tool to make a token? Orion tools, Smithii etc? And if I create an SPL Token, and after some time want to change to a Token-2022, can I burn all the tokens and replace them with the new one?

This is a separate set of questions, but I use the CLI for everything. If you want to "upgrade" tokens to token-2022 later, you'll need to provide a separate system for people to claim the new tokens, since you can't burn other people's tokens
